Terrell Rotation
In David Tong's lecture notes on special relativity (p.158 in Section 7.6.2), it is mentioned that Terrell rotation (also known as the Penrose-Terrell effect) does not alter the shape of a sphere despite Lorentz contraction effects. However, the notes do not provide a detailed proof of this statement. Why is the celestial sphere undistorted by a relativistic observer?
Relevant Excerpt from the Notes:

The first observer saw an object which had the shape of a circle. Based on the arguments of Lorentz contraction, you might expect that the second observer sees a squashed circle, maybe an ellipse. Yet this is not what happens. Instead, the second observer also sees a circle! The effects of the time of flight of light completely eliminate the Lorentz contraction. This fact was only realised more than 50 years after Einstein’s formulation of special relativity when it was discovered independently by Terrell and Penrose. It is sometimes said to be the “invisibility of the Lorentz contraction”.


The Terrell rotation has nothing to do with Lorentz transformations. It occurs only upon considering the time taken for the light from the object to reach a fixed point detector in space.

As such, it is unclear what you mean. The two are distinct effects. The Lorentz transformation of a sphere is simply a contracted sphere.

I am sorry. I meant Lorentz contraction. My mistake.

https://opg.optica.org/josaa/fulltext.cfm?uri=josaa-41-7-1329&id=551632

@Vincent Thacker I think it is clear what the OP means. Because of Lorentz transformation, you would expect a moving sphere to look distorted. However that expectation is because we are used to correcting for light-travel-time effects. In actually looking at the moving sphere, it actually looks spherical.

@D.Halsey "Because of Lorentz transformation, you would expect a moving sphere to look distorted" As mentioned in my first comment, that is false. The Lorentz transformation does not distort the shape of an object; it only contracts its length. The apparent rotation is because of the different travel times of light from different points of the object to the detector. This effect is independent of relativity. Anyone who claims that Lorentz transformations include light travel time to the eye grossly misunderstands relativity.

@Vincent Thacker Maybe "distorted'" wasn't the best word to use. What I meant was  "no longer spherical" which you seem to be agreeing with. I also didn't claim that Lorentz transformations included light travel time. Just the opposite - that as a result, the visual appearance is not what you would expect without correcting for that effect.

If you look at a spherical object moving at relativistic speeds it will appear spherical, as explained in Terrell's paper Invisibility of the Lorentz Contraction.
For a more detailed discussion of distortion of images of objects moving at relativistic speeds, see Geometric construction of relativistic and non-relativistic distortion by Wells et al. and references therein.

thank you. But I want a proof using spinors the way he used it in the lecture notes.
